# How to use "Requirement-based suite" (Azure DevOps) when testing same user story in multiple environments

Tags: testing, azure-devops, manual-testing

I relate testing to the user stories by creating a requirement-base suite in ADO. When I do this, the user story shows this beaker on the user story, indicating whether testing passed, failed, etc.:

[image]

I've noticed if you relate multiple requirement-based suites to the same user story, the newest testing results overwrites what the beaker shows. For example, in my case, stories progress from lower environments to higher environments (in my instance; dev, QA (functional testing), UAT (regression testing), prod). I can't use the same requirement-based suite for both QA and UAT because I'd have to reset the tests which would lose the results of the lower environment. So, I have to create a new requirement-based suite for the higher environment and relate it to the same user story. When I do this, the new suite results overwrites the results for the lower environment when looking at the beaker. In other words, if I have one test in QA and one in UAT, both related to the user story, the beaker will only reflect one test, not both.

What I think should happen is the beaker shows the testing from the lower and higher environment.

Am I doing this right?

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce this situation on my side, this could be by design. The beaker in the card will only display the outcome from the higher-configuration testing.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the response. I'm not a tester so I'm wondering how testers normally handle this situation. Do they create a user story for the testing in QA (relate a requirement-based suite to it) and another user story for regression testing with its own requirement-based suite?

Comment: A userstory corresponds to a requirement-based suite. We need to create a requirement-based suite for each one. You can refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/create-a-test-plan?view=azure-devops#add-a-requirement-based-test-suite-and-select-backlog-items-to-test) .